# Why this Scala code execute two Futures in one thread?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency

I've been using multiple threads for a long time, yet can not explain such a simple case.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent._
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))

def addOne(x: Int) = Future(x + 1)
def addTwo(x: Int) = Future {addOne(x + 1)}

addTwo(1)
// res5: Future[Future[Int]] = Future(Success(Future(Success(3))))
```

To my surprise, it works. And I don't know why.

**Question:**
Why given *one* thread can it execute two Futures at the same time?

**My expectation**:
The first `Future` (`addTwo`) is occupying the one and only thread (`newFixedThreadPool(1)`), then it calls another `Future` (`addOne`) which again needs another thread.
So the program should end up starved for threads and get stuck.

Comment: There is only one thread, but there is also an unbounded queue that will take all Futures that cannot currently be worked on. Unless any of your futures block, they will eventually finish and the next one from the queue will get processed. But yes, if you block that one thread, everything gets stuck. `def addThree(x) = Future(Await.result(addOne(x)))` would do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that your code is working, is that both futures will be executed by the same thread. The `ExecutionContext` that you are creating will not use a `Thread` directly for each `Future` but will instead schedule tasks (`Runnable` instances) to be executed. In case no more threads are available in the pool these tasks will be put into a `BlockingQueue` waiting to be executed. (See [ThreadPoolExecutor API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for details)

If you look at the implementation of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)` you'll see that creates an Executor with an unbounded queue:

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue[Runnable])
```

To get the effect of thread-starvation that you were looking for, you could create an executor with a limited queue yourself:

```
 implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, 
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable](1)))
```

Since the minimal capacity of `ArrayBlockingQueue` is 1 you would need three futures to reach the limit, and you would also need to add some code to be executed on the result of the future, to keep them from completing (in the example below I do this by adding `.map(identity)`)

The following example

```
import scala.concurrent._
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, 
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue[Runnable](1)))

def addOne(x: Int) = Future {
  x + 1
}
def addTwo(x: Int) = Future {
  addOne(x + 1) .map(identity)
}
def addThree(x: Int) = Future {
  addTwo(x + 1).map(identity)
}

println(addThree(1))
```

fails with

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable@65a264b6 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@10d078f4[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

expand it to `Promise` is easily to undunderstand

```
val p1 = Promise[Future[Int]]
ec.execute(() => {
  // the fist task is start run
  val p2 = Promise[Int]
  //the second task is submit , but no run
  ec.execute(() => {
    p2.complete(Success(1))
    println(s"task 2 -> p1:${p1},p2:${p2}")
  })
  //here the p1 is completed, not wait p2.future finish
  p1.complete(Success(p2.future))
  println(s"task 1 -> p1:${p1},p2:${p2}")// you can see the p1 is completed but the p2 have not
  //first task is finish, will run second task
})
val result: Future[Future[Int]] = p1.future

Thread.sleep(1000)
println(result)
```